# List PostgreSQL extensions per database

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, postgresql-extensions

I have a Postgres 9.5 server with 30 databases.

I would like to find out which database uses which extension(s) in one go, preferably in a query that is usable in pgAdmin.

I know that `SELECT * FROM pg_extension` gives me the extensions for the database I am connected to.

I also know that `SELECT * FROM pg_available_extensions` lists, well, all available extensions.

I also know that `SELECT * FROM pg_database` lists all existing databases.

**Question**

How can I create a list that includes the database name and the extensions used in each database?

Comment: Possibly the query on the following page can be adapted to get the data you seek: https://tapoueh.org/blog/2019/11/list-postgresql-tables-using-extensions/

Answer (score 0):

You connect to each database in turn and query `pg_extension`.

Comment: Is there away to do this in an automated way? like a script to give to psql or something